# How to avoid duplicating string format with string interpolation

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-interpolation

Is it possible to not repeat the string format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {DateTime.Now.AddDays(1):yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}");
```

Other than with workarounds like:

```
Func<string, object, string> _ = string.Format;
var f = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
Console.WriteLine($"{_(f, DateTime.Now)} {_(f, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1))}")
```

Comment: Use `$"{DateTime.Now.ToString(format)} {DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString(format)}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many fragments to be formatted, I suggest implementing custom culture for this:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

public sealed class MyFormat : IDisposable {
  private CultureInfo m_Saved;
  private CultureInfo m_Current;

  public MyFormat() {
    m_Saved = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    m_Current = new CultureInfo(m_Saved.Name, true);

    m_Current.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    m_Current.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";

    //TODO: Add more formats' specifications here  

    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = m_Current;
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    if (m_Current == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) 
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = m_Saved;
  }
}
```

then you can put it as

```
using (new MyFormat()) {
  Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} {DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this pattern 10 years ago (how time flies!): https://pragmateek.com/c-scope-your-global-state-changes-with-idisposable-and-the-using-statement/#Scoping_change_of_thread_culture

Answer (score 2):

The format you are trying to use is quite similar to one of these:

| Name | Specifier | Format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [The Sortable Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier) | `s` | `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"` |
| [Round-trip Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) | `o` or `O` | `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK"` |
| [Universal Sortable Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-universal-sortable-u-format-specifier) | `u` | `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"` |

If you can use one of them, there is no need to maintain a custom format string.

If not, and you can define the format globally, you could do something like this:

```cs
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new("en-US")
{
    DateTimeFormat =
    {
        ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
        ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss",
    }
};
```

Then, if you run the same call again with the 'g' format (short date + short time), it will respect the global settings:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:g} {DateTime.Now.AddDays(1):g}");
// produces: 2023-03-15 16:43:07 2023-03-16 16:43:07
```

Also, if you know the format you want is the format that is used in a specific culture/country, and you are using it because of that, you could also set the current culture to that directly and not have to customize any of the individual formats.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, could be wrapped in a using like in https://pragmateek.com/c-scope-your-global-state-changes-with-idisposable-and-the-using-statement/#Scoping_change_of_thread_culture

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the string format into the `ToString()` method of `DateTime`

```
const string dtFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
Console.WriteLine($"This is interpolated: {DateTime.Now.ToString(dtFormat)}");
// output: This is interpolated: 2023-03-15 17:48:25
```

More details at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Thanks, it avoids the creation of a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can create static class and provide static property to get always the same format.

```
public static class Utils {
    public static string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public static string PrintDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString(DateFormat);
    }

    public static string Format(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString(DateFormat);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.Write(now.Format()); //2023-03-15 18:50:32
Console.Write(Utils.PrintDate(now)); //2023-03-15 18:50:32
```